# about word-order of a question sentence which is a line from a movie

Tags: grammar, questions, word-order, inversion

I'd like to ask about a line in a dialogue(<- should it be *a line of a dialogue* instead?) from the movie, **No Country for Old Men**.
I marked the line bold among the below dialogue. The conversation happens between the psychopathic killer Anton and the gas station owner, as Anton is about to pay for the snack and gas.

---

Anton: *How much?*

Gas Station Owner: *Sixty-nine cents*

Anton: *And the gas?*

Gas Station Owner: *Y'all getting any rain up your way?*

Anton: *What way would that be?*

Gas Station Owner: *Well, I seen you was from Dallas.*

Anton: ***What business is it of yours where I'm from, friendo?***

Gas Station Owner: *Well, I didn't mean nothing by it.*

---

What I am confused about is the word-order of the sentence.
Isn't it supposed to be

> *What business of yours is it where I'm from?*

rather than

> *What business is it of yours where I'm from?*

Comment: I can't figure any reason other than style for a transposition like that. Both of them are perfectly grammatical (and natively sound) English in my eyes, although I guess I have a preference for the latter. Curiously, though, I did check [ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=business+is+it+of+yours%2Cbusiness+of+yours+is+it&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbusiness%20is%20it%20of%20yours%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbusiness%20of%20yours%20is%20it%3B%2Cc0), and it has a strong preference. Maybe a deeper reason, or maybe just a turn of phrase.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I didn't know the original one is much more preferred. As a non-native English speaker, I thought the latter should be the right one, because ***business*** and ***of yours*** belong to one group in terms of units of meaning just like ***where I'm from*** is one group. I didn't know they can be separated because if the sentence was in a plain mod, not question, it would be *It is **business of yours** where I'm from*.

Comment: A lot of things in English "just stick" because they roll off the tongue or read well. There are oftentimes many valid word orders for a sentence. A guess in the dark as to why the latter is more popular might just be because the emphasized expression "of yours" is happier on its own completely after the "business" part; an unimportant, trailing "is it" makes you have to think back to what it's applying to. But I would be curious as to anyone else's explanation!

Comment: The nationality of the Anton Chigurh character was deliberately not specified, but it is known that when the Coen brothers approached Javier Bardem to play the role, he said, "I don't drive, I speak bad English and I hate violence." The Coens responded, "That's why we called you."

Comment: To this native speaker, the Chigurh character is clearly not one.

Comment: @Feryll I appreciate your continuous comments. The feel you explained about the expression is very helpful for me to understand it.  As you said, the reason may be because "of yours" can be more clearly emphasized in the latter form. In addition, "What business of yours" is a long complicated structure so it might sound a bit overwhelming.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Thank you for the commenting giving extra information about the background of the actor's accent. But I am not sure if I understood your last statement correctly - *To this native speaker, the Chigurh character is clearly not one*. Do you mean that Chigurh character is not the one that speaks proper English?

Comment: @SmartHumanism - exactly that - he has a heavy foreign accent and is not fluent.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I appreciate your reply. Thank you.